# First altcoin with integrated Tor

Tags: altcoin, tor

I'm trying to rebuild the commit history of a coin and it starts with a single dump with a port from another alt. It comes from NovaCoin but has Tor added.

Does anyone know what the first coin with integrated Tor was?

I'm hoping to be able to fork Novacoin and apply the changes made before adding the altcoin I'm on as the difference between it and Novacoin are massive, there's a big chunk of missing history. I've actually traced six coin iterations the code has gone through but there is a missing link!

Comment: What does 'integrated Tor' mean? Bitcoin Core has supported proxying through Tor and running as a hidden service since 2012...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of cryptos use anonymous networks. Look up monero, dash, torcoin and more. They're a ton of anonymous coins out there.

Answer (score -2):

I think Torcoin was the first Altcoin with Tor support. But I can't find an evidence right now.